# How to prevent Vim from loading a specific system-wide ftplugin?

Tags: ftplugin, runtimepath

I'm writing a custom ftplugin for handling `systemd` file type. I've copied parts of code from vim's own systemd ftplugin and now the latter conflicts with my own code:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*/etc/systemd/*.conf"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>1
4_LoadFTPlugin[18]..script /usr/share/vim/vim90/ftplugin/systemd.vim:
line   12:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it: Sman silent exe '!' . KeywordLookup_systemd(<q-args>) | redraw!
```

From what I see, the error comes from the system-wide ftplugin. The problem is, it uses the normal `b:did_ftplugin` guard improperly. Instead of this:

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

...it does this:

```
if !exists('b:did_ftplugin')
  " some code that sets b:did_ftplugin
endif

" some more code
```

As such, the code that is not guarded comes into conflict with my own code.

---

I suppose this is something that should be patched upstream, but in the meantime, is there a way to prevent Vim from loading the system-wide `ftplugin/systemd.vim` and only load mine?

Comment: I suspect the oddness is to support `:runtime ftplugin/systemd.vim`, like for the Man plugin, but I haven’t checked.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble My apologies, I'm fairly new to Vimscript. Could you please explain what exactly is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: I just looked at it, and I was wrong. (See `ftplugin/man.vim` for some serious weirdness.) I'll contact the maintainer and suggest a patch.

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduce systemd2

What you could do is selecting another `filetype` for `systemd` (e.g. `systemd2`) by having a `ftdetect/systemd2.vim` that set it.

`~/vimfiles/ftdetect/systemd2.vim`

```vimscript
" Systemd unit files
au BufNewFile,BufRead */systemd/*.{automount,dnssd,link,mount,netdev,network,nspawn,path,service,slice,socket,swap,target,timer}    setf systemd2
" Systemd overrides
au BufNewFile,BufRead */etc/systemd/*.conf.d/*.conf setf systemd2
au BufNewFile,BufRead */etc/systemd/system/*.d/*.conf   setf systemd2
au BufNewFile,BufRead */.config/systemd/user/*.d/*.conf setf systemd2
" Systemd temp files
au BufNewFile,BufRead */etc/systemd/system/*.d/.#*  setf systemd2
au BufNewFile,BufRead */etc/systemd/system/.#*      setf systemd2
au BufNewFile,BufRead */.config/systemd/user/*.d/.#*    setf systemd2
au BufNewFile,BufRead */.config/systemd/user/.#*    setf systemd2
```

The `ftplugin/systemd.vim` and friends (`$VIMRUNTIME/indent/systemd.vim`, `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/systemd.vim`, `$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/systemd.vim`) will not be executed anymore and you can put your code in `~/vimfiles/ftplugin/systemd2.vim` and friends.

## Amend the standard solution

Another solution is to amend the `systemd` standard solution by moving part your code in `~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/systemd.vim` and make use of the `command!` to override the `Sman` command if you need to change it.

Comment: Thank you! It did not even cross my mind that I could just introduce another filetype :-)

Comment: +1 for overriding in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/systemd.vim`

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in a recent [runtime commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/5036e698520b2c39e4df5738f026a68ba2e76fef). If you can run recent versions, you should be able to get the upstream change and continue as usual.